# Rails 5 actioncable as a standalone server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, actioncable

There's not TOO much documentation on action cable so I'm a little lost on this.
I'm playing with a rails 5 app, and I'm trying to use the rails5 app as purely an api and hosting my JS elsewhere. So when I start my actioncable server, i am able to connect to the websocket pretty easily just using my built in browser socket support with:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('localhost:3000/cable')
// and then do
socket.onmessage = function(data) { console.log(data) }
```

I connect successfully. I'm getting pings in the form of

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"type":"ping","message":1462992407}", ... etc
```

Except I can't seem to broadcast any messages down to the client. I tried:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast('test',{ yes: true })
```

But only the pings come in. ActionCable comes with its own concepts that I haven't wrapped my head around fully yet like channels and stuff which "just work" in rails apps. But how can I successfully build a separate standalone JS app using actioncable's socket server?

Answer (score 0):

I use ActionCable with an iOS application. Everything works just fine.

ActionCable uses pub/sub pattern.

> Pub/Sub, or Publish-Subscribe, refers to a message queue paradigm
>   whereby senders of information (publishers), send data to an abstract
>   class of recipients (subscribers), without specifying individual
>   recipients. Action Cable uses this approach to communicate between the
>   server and many clients.

Which means that you should create a new channel first,

`rails g channel my_channel`

Then in your channel send some test message:

```
# app/channels/my_channel.rb
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "my_channel"
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "my_channel", 'Test message'
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Then send the following to your server:

```
{'command': 'subscribe', 'identifier': {\'channel\':\'MyChannel\'}}
```

In return you'll get your first frame.